# Автономные транзакции в цикле

Tags: firebird, sql

Добрый день.

Есть код на PSQL, в котором в цикле (около 10 000 итераций) запускается процедура в режиме in autonomous transaction do. Эта процедура работает с одной и той же таблицей, но с разными записями.

В связи с чем два вопроса:

1. Возможны ли конфликты?
2. Главный вопрос - стартуют ли следующие транзакции в цикле, не дожидаясь завершения предыдущих? Если да, то как можно "заставить" их выполняться последовательно, но с commit'ом по завершении (для экономии памяти).

Comment: А что показывают эксперименты? Вы словили блокировки / сжирание памяти или гипотетически опасаетесь?

Comment: Один раз, когда процедуру с циклом запустил два раза подряд - словил блокировки. Насчет памяти не гипотетически опасаюсь, просто объем данных очень большой, и вижу как всё идет в swap. 
Меня больше расстраивает возможность того, что все 10 000 транзакций пойдут одновременно. Мне это не нужно.

Comment: Попробуйте тогда цикл перенести на сторону клиента.

Comment: Спасибо за идею, но клиента нет. Точнее клиент есть, но доступа к его коду нет. Можно написать отдельный клиент, но для задачи (расчет и назначение групп ABC товарам) он не очень требуется.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте избежать вызова 10 000 транзакций. Внутренность процедуры изменить так чтобы не возникал ROLLBACK. И вызывайте процедуру в одной транзакции c блокированием затронутых таблиц:

SET TRANSACTION 
READ WRITE 
RESERVING <tables> 
FOR SHARED READ

http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-set-trans.html

Ещё многое зависит от проектировки БД. Лучше сразу избегать множественных UPDATE. Скажем, INSERT во временную таблицу не вызовет блокировки.

Comment: Цикла, увы, не избежать (10 магазинов по 1000 групп товаров). Я autonomous transaction использую не для того, чтобы при rollback данные оставались, а для того, чтобы промежуточные данные коммитились. В самих вызовах rollback маловероятен.

Если не использовать autonomous transaction, то цикл гарантированно выполнит расчеты последовательно, только памяти запросит очень много. С autonomous transaction на неплохом вобщем-то железе и так 4 часа считает.

Comment: Меня смущает больше всего возможность того, что следующий код за пределами вызвавшей процедуры может начать выполняться раньше в случае с autonomous transaction. Возможно ли это?

Comment: "Главный вопрос - стартуют ли следующие транзакции в цикле, не дожидаясь завершения предыдущих?"

Пишут о вероятности deadlock:
"Warning
Because the autonomous transaction is independent from the one from which is launched, you need to use this feature with caution to avoid deadlocks."

Скорее всего транзакции стартуют последовательно, но если один из запрошенных ресурсов уже занят основной транзакцией то автономная никогда не сможет его захватить и будет гарантированный deadlock.

Начнёт ли код за пределами вызвавшей процедуры выполняться раньше - можно добавить генератор и посчитать вызовы.

Comment: О, спасибо. Теперь прояснилось. Дедлоки я действительно ловил, но когда обращался к одинаковым записям в таблице, подряд запуская цикл два раза. Теперь я его подряд не запускаю, и вроде все в порядке.